# How to add allegro Library in CMake?

Tags: cmake, clion, allegro

What's the path I must to put in cmakelist?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(trabajo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(trabajo main.cpp)


target_link_libraries(trabajo - lmingw32 - allegro_acodec-5.0.10-md-debug)
```

Comment: "What's the path I must to put in cmakelist?" - In `target_link_libraries` call you need to specify **absolute path** to the library.

Comment: You can use either [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) or [`target_link_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_directories.html) to tell CMake where the libraries are found.